# SVG doesn't shrink using Tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working on a react-tailwind project. In src folder I've got an App.js file and App.css which is an output for my Tailwindcss. I have two more folders: components and pages. While adding tailwind classes in the main file (App.js) everything works fine, but trying to change the size of the SVG in Header.jsx inside components folder doesn't work.

Here's one of the SVG elements.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 flex-no-shrink fill-current">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 12L3.269 3.126A59.768 59.768 0 0121.485 12 59.77 59.77 0 013.27 20.876L5.999 12zm0 0h7.5" />
            </svg>
```

I have already tried to import css file to the Header.jsx but it didn't work neither. Also tried to change viewBox but that's not what I wanted to achieve

Comment: Do any Tailwind classes work in your Header.jsx?  Is it just the SVG that's not behaving as expected?  And, how are you using the SVG?  Is it directly in your markup or are you importing?

Comment: We need more information. Show as code of files where you are using svg

Comment: Make sure that the tailwind config file is set to track the Jsx file in question.
Review the contents of `flex-no-shrink` class and see if this is blocking your from changing the size?
After that, try changing `w-4` and `h-4` to something different value like `w-12` and `h-12` and see if the size is changing now. If not, then add more context to the question.

Thank you, hope this helps.